# Display distinct values only, if size is not equal to desired length return to loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to display 10 quotes randomly, but I dont not want duplicates( need to be all different). So I pushed the quotes into an array and then added that array to a set, knowing a set will remove all duplicates. The problem is adding them to a set will remove duplicates and I will not retrieve as many quotes I wanted, but it will have no duplicates.

```
const refreshQuotes = (count:number):any => {
  let quotesSelectedFromPool = [];
  
  let myArray = [];
  let mySet = new Set();
  for (let n:number=0; n<count; n++) {
    let index:number = getRandom(0, quotesArchive.length - 1);
    myArray.push(quotesArchive[index]);
    quotesSelectedFromPool.push(quotesArchive[index]);
  
    console.log(quotesSelectedFromPool[n].id);
    mySet.add(quotesArchive[index]);
    myArray = Array.from(mySet);
    console.log(myArray);
    
 }
  let a = myArray.length;
  if (a == count){
    console.log("its equal");
    if (mySet.size == count){
      console.log(mySet.size, "this is my set size");
      return quotesSelectedFromPool = Array.from(mySet);
   }

  } else if ( a !== count){
  refreshQuotes(count);
}
 return quotesSelectedFromPool = Array.from(mySet);
```

What am I missing here? Am I going about it the right way? I know there is many ways to do this but I thought this way would work, any suggestions..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
const quotesArchive = [
  "this is a test 1",
  "this is a test 2",
  "this is a test 3",
  "this is a test 4",
  "this is a test 5",
  "this is a test 6",
  "this is a test 7",
  "this is a test 8",
  "this is a test 9",
  "this is a test 10"
];

const getRandomQuotes = (count) => {

  // array to hold random quotes
  const retrievedQuotes = [];

  // loop until the count is 0
  while (count > 0) {

    // get a random integer between 1 and 10
    const idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    
    // get the quote from the archive
    const quote = quotesArchive[idx];

    // if the quote is not already in the retrieved list, add it
    if (!retrievedQuotes.includes(quote)) {
      retrievedQuotes.push(quote);
      // decrement the count of quotes that is left to retrieve
      count--;
    }
  }

  return retrievedQuotes;
};

// pass in whatever count you want between 1 and 10
console.log(getRandomQuotes(2));
```

Comment: I am not getting duplicates with your way, but it does not always give me the desired amount of quotes I asked for every time.. ?

Comment: put count-- inside the if statement

Comment: Oh yeah. That’s right. I didn’t test it thoroughly. Good catch. Updated now